# Factoring a projection of surface groups through a free group

Tags: gr.group-theory, surfaces

Consider the surface group $S_g=\langle a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,\dots,a_g,b_g \mid [a_1,b_1][a_2,b_2]\cdots[a_{g},b_{g}]=1\rangle$, which is the fundamental group of the closed orientable genus-$g$ surface.

Suppose $2\leq m<n$ and let $p:S_n\to S_m$ be the canonical projection, which is the identity on generators $a_i,b_i$, $1\leq i\leq m$ and which trivializes $a_i,b_i$, $m+1\leq i\leq n$. Let $F_r$ denote the free group with rank $r$.

**Question:** Is it possible to have finite rank free group $F_r$ and epimorphisms $f:S_n\to F_r$ and $g:F_r\to S_m$ such that $g\circ f=p$?

There is apparently a kind of classification of epimorphisms of surface groups onto free groups that seems relevant (in the following reference). However, I have not been able to see exactly how it helps answer this question.

> R. I. Grigorchuk, P. F. Kurchanov, and H. Zieschang, “Equivalence of homomorphisms of surface groups to free groups and some properties of 3-dimensional handlebodies,” Preprint, Ruhr-Universität Bochum, 1990.

The classification: If $r>n$, then no epimorphism $S_n\to F_r$ can exist. Apparently, when $r\leq n$, then there is only one epimorphism $S_n\to F_r$ "up to automorphism." The representative is this: choose $F:S_n\to F_r$ to send $a_i$, $1\leq i\leq r$ to the free generators and trivialize all other generators. This is unique in the sense that for any other epimorphism $f:S_n\to F_r$, we must have $F=f\circ \sigma$ for some $\sigma\in Aut(S_n)$.

Considering this classification and the structure of $p$, my feeling is that the question has a negative answer but that I am perhaps overlooking something simple.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The homomorphism $p$ is non-trivial on second (co)homology, since it is induced by a degree one map of surfaces ("collapse $n-m$ holes to a point"). This can also be seen using the structure of the cohomology rings of orientable surfaces.

Hence no such factorisation exists, as free groups have zero (co)homology above dimension one.